# Flask-sqlalchemy disable autoflush for the whole session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-sqlalchemy, how can I just configure it for `no autoflush`. Currently I am doing something like

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
...
db.init_app(app)
...
db.session.configure(autoflush=False)
```

But it gives error. How to fix this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `session_options` parameter can be used to override session options. If provided it’s a dict of parameters passed to the session’s constructor.

```
 db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={"autoflush": False})
```